# Visual GUI Buider

Tags: eclipse, gwt, grails, netbeans

Is there a visual GUI builder, such as GWTDesigner that one could use in developing with Grails? I am new to Grails and am presently working from the command line and using a text editor. I have briefly looked at using Eclipse and Netbeans as IDEs. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a specific GUI builder for Grails, but if I'd had to choose between Eclipse and Netbeans, then Netbeans clearly wins here - I'd start with it. Just make sure you install Grails support in Netbeans first.